# React Native AWS Location

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, expo, heap-memory

I am trying to create a mobile app and use AWS location trackers. I have the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk-react-native';

export default function App() {
  const client = new AWS.Location({
    region: 'eu-west1',
    credentials: {
         ...
    }
  })
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text> Altitude</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

And I get a fatal error which I have never encountered before.

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[33230:0x561df76b3e60]    55471 ms: Mark-sweep 1965.5 (2085.9) -> 1961.2 (2092.1) MB, 4608.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.536, current mu = 0.059) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[33230:0x561df76b3e60]    60543 ms: Mark-sweep 1977.7 (2092.1) -> 1972.3 (2098.1) MB, 5041.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.335, current mu = 0.006) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

 1: 0x561df464fc81 node::Abort() [/usr/bin/node]
 2: 0x561df4556d9b node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [/usr/bin/node]
 3: 0x561df4829ea2 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/bin/node]
 4: 0x561df482a108 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/bin/node]
 5: 0x561df49cc6c6  [/usr/bin/node]
 6: 0x561df49dd962 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/bin/node]
 7: 0x561df49dfc5a v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithLightRetrySlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin,



v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/bin/node]
 8: 0x561df49dfce7 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/bin/node]
 9: 0x561df49a39dd v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [/usr/bin/node]
10: 0x561df4cdf6db v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/bin/node]
11: 0x561df50845d9  [/usr/bin/node]
```

I would be grateful if someone can provide me with some tips for dealing with this issue. Note that I removed all useless parts of the code in order to reproduce the bug.
Thank you!

Comment: Is this reproduce locally or only after deploy?

Comment: Locally after trying to connect my android device to expo by scanning the QR

Comment: You can try to add NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096 to start command in `expo start`
It once helped me in case closer to you
Looks like work around if works, but maybe helps

Comment: Do I just export it as an environmental variable?

Comment: Yes, you can set it on windows like `set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096`

Comment: Does not seem to be working, I am using linux and I added the export but I encounter the same bug

Comment: Interesting. For to be sure, i'd suggest to try 
npm i -D cross-env
```add the following to "scripts" in package.json "start": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096 expo start"```
and run `npm run start`, as i understood u r using expo
No other ideas for now :(